# Replace random value in string with random value

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, random

virus is supposed to be a string of nucleotides, and the function should return a string consisting of the same amount of nucleotides, but one is changed.

```
def mutate(virus):
    mutations = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
    virus.split
    random.randrange(1, stop=len(virus), step=1) = random.choice(mutations)
```

so for example if the virus is ATCG it should return something like ATCC or GTCG, how can I go about this, I tried making virus into a list, and replacing a random variable in it with a random of my possible mutations list.

So it should probably make a list from the string virus, do a mutation, put the list back into a string and return the string.

Comment: How many letters are supposed to be change ? is this random also ?

Comment: If this is a part of a genetic algorithm and will be repeated many times, consider using a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random index to replace at and a random value:

```
import random
def mutate(virus):
   mutations = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
   i = random.randint(0, len(virus)-1)
   val = random.choice(mutations)
   return ''.join(val if c == i else a for c, a in enumerate(virus))
```

Comment: Maybe use range/slice syntax instead of the explicit loop? `virus[:i] + val + virus[1+i:]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do sth. like the following:

```
def mutate(virus):
    # choose random index to change
    index = random.randint(0, len(virus) - 1)

    # make sure you are not using the previous char by removing it from 
    # the mutations to choose from
    mutations = [c for c in 'ATCG' if c != virus[index]]

    # swap out the char at index with a random mutation
    return virus[:index] + random.choice(mutations) + virus[index+1:]
```

Comment: hey man, changed index to i aswell, now it works! i love you, can you explain your code a bit? i see that you used list slicing.

Comment: @RubenWeijers No, those are slices of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import random
def mutate(virus):
    mutations = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
    r = random.randint(0, len(virus)-1)
    virus = list(virus)
    virus[r] = random.choice(mutations)
    return ''.join(virus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since string are immutable, I would recommend working with list instead of string. Readability will be increase also in my opinion.

```
import random
def mutate(virus):
    mutations = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
    virus = list(virus)
    virus[random.randint(0, len(virus)-1)] = random.choice(mutations)
    return "".join(virus)
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(mutate('ATCG'))
ATCT

>>> print(mutate('ATCG'))
ATTG

>>> print(mutate('ATCG'))
ATCC
```